# Can one intercept data outside of their local network?

Tags: security, networking, ip

Is it possible to access and intercept data transmissions between two hosts which are on separate subnets but still on the internet.

example say intercepting two hosts located in say japanese ISP subnet by an attacker located in a US ISP subnet without the use of malware or physical access or ISP intervention?

or is it just movie stuff?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's better suited for http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are things you can do, to gain access to specific users data-streams with sufficient time, effort and energy. It does not require malware or viruses, nor does it require physical access to the target networks. 
What is *does* require is persistence and an awful lot of late nights and long days, filled with, quite often not a great deal beyond probes and tests for vulnerable network or user kit. Once you find a way through perimeter firewalls and networks, there is still a fair amount of work to go, however, there are things you can do on perimeter routers and switches, that allows you to dump copious amounts of data, flowing across the ports to a disk or elsewhere for inspection and  fact-finding on your theoretical targets..

This is just one, very quickly drafted way, of achieving your specified goal - but I can assure you, it is almost never like you see it at the movies..
HTH